# Não consigo visualizar saída no console em projeto com Wildfly

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly

Não consigo visualizar nenhuma saída no console num projeto com Wildfly 8.0.0.

Se em qualquer ponto do meu código eu faço um `System.out.println("Qualquer coisa")` simplesmente não aparece nada no meu console do Eclipse Kepler.

O mesmo projeto rodando com Apache Tomcat 7 gera saída no console sem problema.

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servidores de aplicação são um pouco mais complexos, e utilizam loggers para isso. A saida padrão não é a mesma quem um app desktop, por exemplo.
Para você poder devidamente ver esse log você deve usar algo do tipo:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
...

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SuaClasse.class.getName());
```

Depois disso é simples:

```
log.info("Mensagem");
log.warning("Mensagem");
log.severe("Mensagem");
log...
```

Agora você terá seus logs no console da IDE, adicionalmente você pode consultar o arquivo de log dentro do servidor, na pasta /standalone/log/server.log

Abraços